# Image not loading in vue.js

Tags: dynamic, vue.js, imagesource

I am trying to dynamically generate images in my vue.js project by creating a basic method:

```
  methods: {
    changeLang(la
    getImg(image, ext) {
      return '~@/assets/images/' + image + '.' + ext;
    },
      ...
```

Each component will have it's images generated dynamically:

```
data () {
    return {
      cat:'frenchcat',
      ...
```

The following line should identify the method, image and date and convert it into the image URL

```
<img v-bind:src="getImg(cat, 'svg')" v-bind:alt=cat>
```

But for some reason the source code simply returns:

```
<img data-v-61dd7a3d src="~@/assets/images/frenchcat.svg" alt="frenchcat"/>
```

Why is `~@/assets/` not being converted into an URL path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `require` with `v-bind:src`:

```
getImg(image, ext) {
      return require(`~@/assets/images/${image}.${ext}`);
}
```

Unsure if `~` before `@` is needed.

Comment: I am getting `* ~@/assets/images in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Header.vue` error